How to get rid of quotes around bash arguments stored in array?
DNF_OPTS=('--disableplugin=subscription-manager' '--disablerepo=*' '--enablerepo=a,b,c')

dnf update -y "${DNF_OPTS[@]}" some-pkg

The command is executed as:
dnf update -y --disableplugin=subscription-manager '--disablerepo=*' '--enablerepo=a,b,c'

Note the single quotes around the --disablerepo and --enablerepo arguments -- how do I get rid of them?

Are you using the output of set -x/bash -x to determine what "The command is executed as"? If so, then the quotes are not part of what gets executed. Post the actual problem you have, not what you might think it is.

"The command is executed as" – I doubt it, I expect --enablerepo=a,b,c to be there twice. The line is not consistent with the code above it. Where did you get the line from? In case you made it up only to show us what you think is executed then please state this clearly.

Hmm, Bash's set -x doesn't even single-quote that --enablerepo=a,b,c (no need, as the comma isn't special). ksh's does, but it also single quotes --disableplugin=.... (What logic it uses is also rather curious, since it doesn't quote something like --foo or foo=bar.) So, yeah, I also wonder where that came from.

I didn't meant to include --enablerepo=... in the dnf command, sorry. And I figured this out, I had an extra set of single quotes which were causing the problem.

There is no quote in those array elements:
bash-5.1$ DNF_OPTS=('--disableplugin=subscription-manager' '--disablerepo=*' '--enablerepo=a,b,c')

bash-5.1$ typeset -p DNF_OPTS
declare -a DNF_OPTS=([0]="--disableplugin=subscription-manager" [1]="--disablerepo=*" [2]="--enablerepo=a,b,c")

bash-5.1$ (set -o xtrace; printf '<%s>\n' "${DNF_OPTS[@]}")
+ printf '<%s>\n' --disableplugin=subscription-manager '--disablerepo=*' --enablerepo=a,b,c
<--disableplugin=subscription-manager>
<--disablerepo=*>
<--enablerepo=a,b,c>

As you can see from the output of printf, printf received those arguments without quotes.
Quotes were used in the shell syntax of the array assignment to protect special characters in the value of the elements.
For instance * is special in the syntax of the shell and array=( --disablerepo=* ) would have caused $array to contain all the filenames in the current working directory that start with --disablerepo (and if there was no such file, and error if failglob was enabled, nothing if nullglob was enabled or --disablerepo=* otherwise), so you were right to use quotes there.
You'll notice that both typeset -p and the xtrace tracing produce shell code that could be used to reconstruct the same array and run the same command respectively.
In the case of typeset -p, all values were quoted with double quotes, in the case of xtrace, only the ones that needed to be quoted and with single quotes, that's just a choice of coding style, xtrace could as well have output:
'printf' '<%s>\n' '--disableplugin=subscription-manager' '--disablerepo=*' '--enablerepo=a,b,c'

Here quoting all the printf arguments and with single quotes, the strong form of quotes. Or in other words, only leaving unquoted the character that must remain unquoted so it retains its special meaning as an argument delimiter: the space character.
Or:
printf \<%s">"'\'n --disableplugin=subscription-manager --disablerepo=$'*' --enablerepo=a,b,c

Here using all 4 shell quoting operators in the bash language syntax (\, "...", '...', $'...', here omitting $"..." which does localisation in addition to quoting) and only for the characters that need that quoting (<, > which are redirection operators, \ which is a quoting operator and * a globbing operator).
Both of which being shell code which once interpreted by the shell would result in the same command being executed with the same list of arguments.
For those array elements to contain those quotes, you'd have had to write the assigment something like:
DNF_OPTS=(
  --disableplugin=subscription-manager
  "'--disablerepo=*'"
  \'--enablerepo=a,b,c\'
)

Here quoting the single quotes with "..." or \ so they are included literally in the value of the elements.
Then:
bash-5.1$ (set -o xtrace; printf '<%s>\n' "${DNF_OPTS[@]}")
+ printf '<%s>\n' --disableplugin=subscription-manager ''\''--disablerepo=*'\''' ''\''--enablerepo=a,b,c'\'''
<--disableplugin=subscription-manager>
<'--disablerepo=*'>
<'--enablerepo=a,b,c'>

The xtrace output is a bit clunky there. The single quote was quoted as \', but there are other single quoted strings around it including empty '' ones which make it harder to read.
